# JSON parsing array into objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have an array of components like this:

```
var names =
    1)"lat: 40.6447077, lng: -73.878421, address: 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Brooklyn, NY 11239, USA"
    2)"lat: 40.609099, lng: -73.931516, address: 2015 E. 35th street, Brooklyn, Ny, United States"
```

I am trying to parse this into an array of objects. The following code works great for parsing the latitude and longitude, yet am receiving unexpected token errors when attempting to parse the address too.

```
    var newArray = names.map(function (str) {
    return JSON.parse("{" + str.replace(/lat/, '"lat"').replace(/lng/, '"lng"').replace(/address/, '"address"').replace(/;/, "") + "}")
});
```

Comment: What is source of these strings? fixing source would be first choice

Comment: @charlietfl, its from an MVC view. How should i change the source fields?

Comment: presumably that data is being turned into string from some initial organized structure. Creating proper json at that point would simplify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strings in JSON must be in doublequotes.

Replace `(/address/, '"address"')` in your code with `(/address: (.+)/, '"address": "$1"')`

Answer (score 0):

```
names.map(function (str) {
  return JSON.parse(
    "{" + str.replace(/address: /, 'address: "').replace(/(\w+): /g, '"$1": ')+'"}'
  );
});
```

You have first to wrap the address date within quotes, as it is not only text but has commas in it. Confusion galore. Then you wrap words before `:` within quotes too.